# Run Json link in Browser in android

Tags: android, json, browser, webview

I'm need to run Json link in Browser but I do not want to open the browser.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.JsonLink.com");
```

This code open me in Browser.
I need this open in the background.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a JSON object from a URL, try this code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if(ni != null && ni.isConnected()){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL url = new URL("http://yourlink.com/");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(15000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            int response = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("Response", Integer.toString(response));
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(String line=null; (line=reader.readLine())!=null;){
                builder.append(line);
            }
            con.disconnect();
            String jsonString = new String(builder.toString());
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                //TODO: Your error handling
            }
        }
    }).start();
}else{
    Log.d("Network", "Not Connected");
}
```

Note that this is done on a separate thread since we are doing a network operation. You will need to either define `jsonObj` outside the thread, or send it to your main thread in a different way if you need to do UI updates, etc.

Hope this helps!